# How to do odata webservice Delete operation using jquery?

Tags: jquery, web-services, jquery-plugins, odata

I have created a jquery plugin to perform delete operation in Odata webservice. I utlised the sample odata url link for my practice section.

**url**: `http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers`

**My JQuery Plugin:**

```
(function ($) {
    var settings = {
        url: 'http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/'
    };
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options)
        },

    DeleteService: function (uniqueID) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers" + "(" + uniqueID + ")",
                    type: "DELETE"
                })
                debugger;
            }


        };

        $.fn.accessWebService = function (methodName) {
            if (methods[methodName]) {
                // Method exists.
                return methods[methodName].apply(
                    this,
                    Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
                );
            } else if (typeof methodName === 'object' || !methodName) {
                // No method called, default to init
                return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
            } else {
                // Method does not exists.
                $.error('Method ' + methodName + ' does not exist.');
            }
        };
    }(jQuery));
```

I am calling this function on `button-click` from html

```
<input type="submit" id="delete" onclick="$(this).accessWebService('DeleteService', document.getElementById('categoryid').value)" value="Delete" />
```

My data not getting deleted I am facing the same issue in `post` operation also.

I couldn't figure out where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your service name inside `method` object is `DeleteService` and you are trying to invoke `ODataDeleteService` ??? am i missing something?

Comment: check the network tab for any requests

Comment: @CerlinBoss. I checked that too. Initially jquery hitting the service URL and its in pending state. After application got fully loaded the service url getting vanished from the network tab.